# How to save data using nested Resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am practising on Rails and having hard times with nested resources.
I got authors,books and genres in my DB. I have added a nested resource on `routes.rb` :

```
  resources :authors do
    resources :books
  end
```

I can see the new route by `rake routes`: `new_author_book`.

I added a link to the author-`show.html.erb` :

```
<%= link_to "Add a Book to This Author" , new_author_book_path(@author) %>
```

So this link redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/authors/[author_id]/books/new`

I can see the author_id correctly by using `params[:author_id]` in new.html.erb(Books)

I tried to find that author in the `books_controller` by using:

```
def create
  @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
  @book = @author.book.create(book_params)
end
```

But error occurs as, `Couldn't find Author without an ID`

I used scaffolding to create these tables and relations.

This is my `_form.html.erb` partial (Books)

```
<%= form_with(model: book, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if book.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% book.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :release %>
    <%= form.text_field :release %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the `books_contollers#new`,

```
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end
```

LAST STATUS OF APP:

```
books_controller.rb :

  def new
    @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
    @book = @author.books.new
  end

 def create
  @book = Book.create(book_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Server response:

```
Started POST "/authors/11/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-10 13:37:21 +0300
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SHORTENED_THIS==", "book"=>{"name"=>"Shiny Tales", "release"=>"2011", "genre_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Book", "author_id"=>"11"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:29
  Genre Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE `genres`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:29
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:29
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:31
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:31
  Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered books/_form.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 20.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

I tried to follow Rails Guides adding a second model 
section but I think this is a bit different.

I don't want to do any author selection or something like that in this situation because I already selected an author in the author-`show.html.erb`

Comment: Please show the `new` action code

Comment: @Vasfed added to the main post.

Comment: this is because `author_id` is present in `new action` but not submitted in your form to `create action`

Comment: @G.B so how can i submit it ?

Comment: There are multiple ways! I have to add them as answer(can't comment them because of length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem by creating a custom function as a `set_author` in `books_controller`

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_author , only: [:new,:create]

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.create(book_params)
    @book.author_id = @author.id
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: In create action `@book = Author.find(params[:author_id]).books.create(book_params)
` could be better instead of making new `set_author` method.

Comment: @ray I can't try this now but everytime i want to use params[:author_id] in create action it was nil.

Comment: @ray okay i tried it. It says "Couldnt find author without an ID"

Comment: Can you explain me, if you do not get `params[:author_id]` in create action then how did you get same in before_action filter `set_author`. Your params should be same for `set_author` & `create`, right?

Comment: @ray I don't know. I can use it on new action but can't use it on create.

Comment: @ray's right - if your code works, `params[:author_id]` in the create action should too. Odd. Glad you got a solution though :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like a little shuffling is needed here. I believe you've got your `new` and `create` actions the wrong way around.

`params[:author_id]` is available to your `new` action, which should look something like:

```
def new
  @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
  @book = @author.books.new
end
```

And then `create` should be:

```
def create
  @book = Book.create(book_params)
end
```

You might well need a field in your `book` form for `author_id`, though I can't recall from the top of my head whether that's necessary. For example:

```
<%= form.hidden_field :author_id, book.author_id %>
```

If doing this, ensure `author_id` is whitelisted in the params in the `books_controllers`:

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:author_id, ... the rest of your attributes)
end
```

---

Additionally, your form should be updated to point to the nested resource ([docs here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with#method-i-form_with-label-Examples)), which will provide `params[:author_id]` to your `create` action, meaning you can keep this as is. You simply pass an array to the form builder, i.e.

```
<%= form_with(model: [@author, @book]) do |form| %>
```

This sets up the form to hit the nested URL with the `author_id` param in place as desired.

If following this approach, your `create` action should look as follows:

```
def create
  @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
  @book = @author.books.create(book_params)
end
```

Hope there's something in there that helps - let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks but what is the build_book? It says "undefined method `build_book' for #<Author:0x00007f9a9aa5c0a8>"

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit of an assumption on my part: for a `belongs_to` relationship, Rails adds a [`build_association`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to) method, and I thought that's what you were using. You can initialise the the book however you want (such as `@book = @author.book.new`) :)

Comment: Did you get this working @Zogimu? Did this help at all?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I am using belongs_to but build_book didn't worked. I tried "@book = @author.books.new" but it still says author must exists.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Zogimu, and no worries on the delay :) I've updated my answer with two points: updating the permitted params for the first option, and the `create` action for the latter. I'd go with the latter personally. Happy to give this a shot? Let me know any feedback / questions!

Comment: author_id is already whitelisted on default. When i add the "@author = Author.find(params[:id])" to create action , errors occurs "Couldn't find Author without an ID" . Let me add the server responses to main post. Appreciated for your help.

Comment: That's my bad @Zogimu - it should have been `@author = Author.find(params[:author_id])`, sorry. Try that in the `create` action and we should have this firing :) BTW, re your comment about not wanting author selection in multiple actions - don't worry about this, it's standard and pretty necessary. It's actually quite conventional to have a [`before_action`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to handle this, but that's for another step in the guide I'm sure!

Comment: still the same error in create action . "Couldn't find Author without an ID". Did you see the server responses ? I don't get it , there is an author_id parameter and it says author needed.

Comment: Agree, it's very odd. That error message suggests `params[:author_id]` is returning `nil` despite what we're seeing, though it would be also worth verifying an author with ID 11 definitely exists. Perhaps try `puts "ID from params: #{params[:author_id]}"; puts "Author: #{Author.find_by_id(params[:author_id])}"` at the start of your `create` action and check the output @Zogimu?

Comment: i added it to create action but i doesn't puts anything to view or server both. I used emma and there is an author with an ID 11.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** Firstly most clean method would be:

```
form_with(model: @author, url: (@book.new_record? ? [@author, @book]: @book))
```

This will lead you to create/update book path with author_id. And in your controller:

```
def create
  @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
  @book = @author.book.create(book_params)
end
```

**2:** Otherwise you can add a hidden_field in your existing form like:

```
<%= form.hidden_field :author_id, params[:author_id] %>
```

and in your controller:

```
def create
  @book = Book.create(book_params)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Is adding hidden_field safe ?

Comment: Is the `id` in the URL safe? If someone can change the hidden_field he can also change the id in the URL. But I would preffer the first solution

Comment: Is there any way to add books "safely" with the button which placed under the authors#show page ?

Comment: If I am not wrong you are worried about User1 updating User2's books. Right? You can use `cancancan` gem to ensure that

Comment: Or else if you are using any `authentication` gem and Author is the logged in user. You can use current session's user to update only his books. He/She won't be able to update others books

Comment: No i don't use. I am practising rails. I tried accepts_nested_attributes in same page and select_tags to save and did it but couldn't do this one(nested resources). Thanks again.

Comment: If your problem is solved by my answer please accept it and help others as well

Comment: This is _very_ similar to my answer @G.B. I noticed another followed one of mine earlier today. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @SRack please see the comments on the question

Comment: What of them @G.B?